# Is there any difference between Spring and Spring.net?

Tags: java, .net, spring, frameworks, spring.net

I've been using Spring with Java and I've seen that there is a version called Spring.NET. I wonder if there is any significant difference between them (apart from that one is for Java and the other is for .NET). Is it just a "language translation" of the framework or are they different project with just a similar purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not a one-to-one language translation. Spring.NET is a independent project which is  based on original Spring. This project has its own architectors and developers. So the details may vary. Besides that Spring.NET project is younger and therefore may be not so fully functional as original Spring.

By the way, you may find more details on this topic [here](http://springframework.net/doc-1.1-M1/reference/html/javadevelopers.html).